# InAppPurchase plugin failing to execute JS callback from Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, in-app-purchase, phonegap-plugins

I’ve created a proof-of-concept PhoneGap app to test out the In-App Purchase mechanism on iOS. The app is based on Phonegap 2.9.0, uses [this InAppPurchase plugin](https://github.com/j3k0/PhoneGap-InAppPurchase-iOS) and is loosely based on [this tutorial](http://fovea.cc/blog/index.php/3-steps-tutorial-for-phonegap-in-app-purchase-on-ios/) which explains how to use the plugin.

The problem is that the Javascript callback function is not being executed by the Objective-C plugin upon successfully receiving InApp Purchase data from the Apple server. I’ve no idea why the JS is not getting executed so hoping someone can spot the problem...?

When I run my app on an iPhone 4S using XCode 4.6.3, everything works up until the StoreKit API asynchronously calls the `productsRequest` success callback in `InAppPurchase.m` upon receiving the product data for the InApp Purchase items. I can see the output of the `NSLog` statement on line 213 which outputs the `callbackArgs` in the XCode log window, which contains the correct details of the InApp Purchase items. The line after that should then result in the Javascript success callback being executed, which is defined on line 128 of `InAppPurchase.js` and passed in on line 140, but the log output at line 129 never appears in the XCode log window.

If I step through the Objective-C using a breakpoint in XCode, I can see that the `callbackId` variable has a sensible value and I can step through `self.plugin.commandDelegate` into the Cordova code to where the JS callback is constructed and this all seems fine but the JS never actually runs.

I also tried using Phonegap 2.7.0 with the app, but the result was the same.

My XCode project for the app can be downloaded [from here](http://ge.tt/1cnJOKo/v/0)

**Update 19/08/2013:** 
The author of [a tutorial on how to use this plugin](http://fovea.cc/blog/index.php/3-steps-tutorial-for-phonegap-in-app-purchase-on-ios) has [confirmed this problem with the plugin is reproducible](http://fovea.cc/blog/index.php/3-steps-tutorial-for-phonegap-in-app-purchase-on-ios/#comment-81) but also has yet to find the cause/solution. I've yet to see an example of this plugin working successfully.

### Source code and output

**Log output from XCode** (excuse the Fraggles and Wombles, I’m a child of the 80’s):

```
2013-08-07 16:16:48.137 InappTest[347:907] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES
2013-08-07 16:16:48.959 InappTest[347:907] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2013-08-07 16:16:49.342 InappTest[347:907] Finished load of: file:///var/mobile/Applications/62132E03-9DE3-4B01-8066-1978CABDD91F/InappTest.app/www/index.html
2013-08-07 16:16:49.479 InappTest[347:907] DEPRECATION NOTICE: The Connection ReachableViaWWAN return value of '2g' is deprecated as of Cordova version 2.6.0 and will be changed to 'cellular' in a future release. 
2013-08-07 16:16:49.514 InappTest[347:907] TRACE: Environment ready
2013-08-07 16:16:49.516 InappTest[347:907] Device ready
2013-08-07 16:16:49.517 InappTest[347:907] Initialising IAP...
2013-08-07 16:16:49.519 InappTest[347:907] InAppPurchase[js]: setup ok
2013-08-07 16:16:49.520 InappTest[347:907] IAP ready
2013-08-07 16:16:49.521 InappTest[347:907] InAppPurchase[js]: load ["uk.co.workingedge.test.inapp.fraggleguide","uk.co.workingedge.test.inapp.wombleguide"]
2013-08-07 16:16:49.522 InappTest[347:907] InAppPurchase[objc]: Getting products data
2013-08-07 16:16:49.524 InappTest[347:907] InAppPurchase[objc]: Set has 2 elements
2013-08-07 16:16:49.525 InappTest[347:907] InAppPurchase[objc]: - uk.co.workingedge.test.inapp.fraggleguide
2013-08-07 16:16:49.526 InappTest[347:907] InAppPurchase[objc]: - uk.co.workingedge.test.inapp.wombleguide
2013-08-07 16:16:49.527 InappTest[347:907] InAppPurchase[objc]: start
2013-08-07 16:16:51.056 InappTest[347:907] InAppPurchase[objc]: productsRequest: didReceiveResponse:
2013-08-07 16:16:51.058 InappTest[347:907] InAppPurchase[objc]: Has 2 validProducts
2013-08-07 16:16:51.058 InappTest[347:907] InAppPurchase[objc]: - uk.co.workingedge.test.inapp.fraggleguide: Fraggle Guide
2013-08-07 16:16:51.062 InappTest[347:907] InAppPurchase[objc]: - uk.co.workingedge.test.inapp.wombleguide: Womble Guide
2013-08-07 16:16:51.065 InappTest[347:907] InAppPurchase[objc]: productsRequest: didReceiveResponse: sendPluginResult: (
        (
                {
            description = "Guide to Fraggles";
            id = "uk.co.workingedge.test.inapp.fraggleguide";
            price = "\U00a30.69";
            title = "Fraggle Guide";
        },
                {
            description = "Guide to Wombles";
            id = "uk.co.workingedge.test.inapp.wombleguide";
            price = "\U00a30.69";
            title = "Womble Guide";
        }
    ),
        (
    )
)
[END OF LOG]
```

**InAppPurchase.m**

```
//
//  InAppPurchase.m
//
//  Created by Matt Kane on 20/02/2011.
//  Copyright (c) Matt Kane 2011. All rights reserved.
//  Copyright (c) Jean-Christophe Hoelt 2013
//

#import "InAppPurchase.h"

// Help create NSNull objects for nil items (since neither NSArray nor NSDictionary can store nil values).
#define NILABLE(obj) ((obj) != nil ? (NSObject *)(obj) : (NSObject *)[NSNull null])

// To avoid compilation warning, declare JSONKit and SBJson's
// category methods without including their header files.
@interface NSArray (StubsForSerializers)
- (NSString *)JSONString;
- (NSString *)JSONRepresentation;
@end

// Helper category method to choose which JSON serializer to use.
@interface NSArray (JSONSerialize)
- (NSString *)JSONSerialize;
@end

@implementation NSArray (JSONSerialize)
- (NSString *)JSONSerialize {
    return [self respondsToSelector:@selector(JSONString)] ? [self JSONString] : [self JSONRepresentation];
}
@end

@implementation InAppPurchase
@synthesize list;

-(void) setup: (CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command {
    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;
    self.list = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
    pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:@"InAppPurchase initialized"];
    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
}

/**
 * Request product data for the given productIds.
 * See js for further documentation.
 */
- (void) load: (CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    NSLog(@"InAppPurchase[objc]: Getting products data");

    NSArray *inArray = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];

    if ((unsigned long)[inArray count] == 0) {
        NSLog(@"InAppPurchase[objc]: empty array");
        NSArray *callbackArgs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: nil, nil, nil];
        CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsArray:callbackArgs];
        [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
        return;
    }

    if (![[inArray objectAtIndex:0] isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
        NSLog(@"InAppPurchase[objc]: not an array of NSString");
        CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_ERROR messageAsString:@"Invalid arguments"];
        [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
        return;
    }

    NSSet *productIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithArray:inArray];
    NSLog(@"InAppPurchase[objc]: Set has %li elements", (unsigned long)[productIdentifiers count]);
    for (NSString *item in productIdentifiers) {
        NSLog(@"InAppPurchase[objc]: - %@", item);
    }
    SKProductsRequest *productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:productIdentifiers];

    BatchProductsRequestDelegate* delegate = [[[BatchProductsRequestDelegate alloc] init] retain];
    delegate.plugin = self;
    delegate.command = command;

    productsRequest.delegate = delegate;
    NSLog(@"InAppPurchase[objc]: start");
    [productsRequest start];
}

- (void) purchase: (CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    NSLog(@"InAppPurchase[objc]: About to do IAP");
    id identifier = [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0];
    id quantity =   [command.arguments objectAtIndex:1];

    SKMutablePayment *payment = [SKMutablePayment paymentWithProduct:[self.list objectForKey:identifier]];
    if ([quantity respondsToSelector:@selector(integerValue)]) {
        payment.quantity = [quantity integerValue];
    }
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}

- (void) restoreCompletedTransactions: (CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
}

// SKPaymentTransactionObserver methods
// called when the transaction status is updated
//
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue*)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray*)transactions
{
    NSString *state, *error, *transactionIdentifier, *transactionReceipt, *productId;
    NSInteger errorCode;

    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        error = state = transactionIdentifier = transactionReceipt = productId = @"";
        errorCode = 0;

        switch (transaction.transactionState)
        {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
                NSLog(@"InAppPurchase[objc]: Purchasing...");
                continue;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                state = @"PaymentTransactionStatePurchased";
                transactionIdentifier = transaction.transactionIdentifier;
                transactionReceipt = [[transaction transactionReceipt] base64EncodedString];
                productId = transaction.payment.productIdentifier;
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                state = @"PaymentTransactionStateFailed";
                error = transaction.error.localizedDescription;
                errorCode = transaction.error.code;
                NSLog(@"InAppPurchase[objc]: error %d %@", errorCode, error);
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                state = @"PaymentTransactionStateRestored";
                transactionIdentifier = transaction.originalTransaction.transactionIdentifier;
                transactionReceipt = [[transaction transactionReceipt] base64EncodedString];
                productId = transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier;
                break;

            default:
                NSLog(@"InAppPurchase[objc]: Invalid state");
                continue;
        }
        NSLog(@"InAppPurchase[objc]: state: %@", state);
        NSArray *callbackArgs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 NILABLE(state),
                                 [NSNumber numberWithInt:errorCode],
                                 NILABLE(error),
                                 NILABLE(transactionIdentifier),
                                 NILABLE(productId),
                                 NILABLE(transactionReceipt),
                                 nil];
        CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = nil;
        pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsArray: callbackArgs];
        NSString *js = [NSString
            stringWithFormat:@"window.storekit.updatedTransactionCallback.apply(window.storekit, %@)",
            [callbackArgs JSONSerialize]];
        NSLog(@"InAppPurchase[objc]: js: %@", js);
        [self.commandDelegate evalJs:js];
        [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
    }
}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    /* NSString *js = [NSString stringWithFormat:
      @"window.storekit.onRestoreCompletedTransactionsFailed(%d)", error.code];
    [self writeJavascript: js]; */
}

- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
{
    /* NSString *js = @"window.storekit.onRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished()";
    [self writeJavascript: js]; */
}

@end

/**
 * Receives product data for multiple productIds and passes arrays of
 * js objects containing these data to a single callback method.
 */
@implementation BatchProductsRequestDelegate

@synthesize plugin, command;

- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest*)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse*)response {

    NSLog(@"InAppPurchase[objc]: productsRequest: didReceiveResponse:");
    NSMutableArray *validProducts = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSLog(@"InAppPurchase[objc]: Has %li validProducts", (unsigned long)[response.products count]);
    for (SKProduct *product in response.products) {
        NSLog(@"InAppPurchase[objc]: - %@: %@", product.productIdentifier, product.localizedTitle);
        [validProducts addObject:
         [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
          NILABLE(product.productIdentifier),    @"id",
          NILABLE(product.localizedTitle),       @"title",
          NILABLE(product.localizedDescription), @"description",
          NILABLE(product.localizedPrice),       @"price",
          nil]];
        [self.plugin.list setObject:product forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", product.productIdentifier]];
    }

    NSArray *callbackArgs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             NILABLE(validProducts),
                             NILABLE(response.invalidProductIdentifiers),
                             nil];

    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult =
      [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsArray:callbackArgs];
    NSLog(@"InAppPurchase[objc]: productsRequest: didReceiveResponse: sendPluginResult: %@", callbackArgs);
    [self.plugin.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:self.command.callbackId];

    [request release];
    [self    release];
}

- (void) dealloc {
    [plugin  release];
    [command release];
    [super   dealloc];
}

@end
```

**InAppPurchase.js**

```
/** 
 * A plugin to enable iOS In-App Purchases.
 *
 * Copyright (c) Matt Kane 2011
 * Copyright (c) Guillaume Charhon 2012
 * Copyright (c) Jean-Christophe Hoelt 2013
 */

cordova.define("cordova/plugin/InAppPurchase", function(require, exports, module) {
    var exec = function (methodName, options, success, error) {
        cordova.exec(success, error, "InAppPurchase", methodName, options);
    };

    var log = function (msg) {
        console.log("InAppPurchase[js]: " + msg);
    };

    var InAppPurchase = function() {
        this.options = {};
    };

    // Error codes.
    InAppPurchase.ERR_SETUP = 1;
    InAppPurchase.ERR_LOAD = 2;
    InAppPurchase.ERR_PURCHASE = 3;

    InAppPurchase.prototype.init = function (options) {
        this.options = {
            ready:    options.ready || function () {},
            purchase: options.purchase || function () {},
            restore:  options.restore || function () {},
            restoreFailed:  options.restoreFailed || function () {},
            restoreCompleted:  options.restoreCompleted || function () {},
            error:    options.error || function () {}
        };

        var that = this;
        var setupOk = function () {
            log('setup ok');
            that.options.ready();

            // Is there a reason why we wouldn't like to do this automatically?
            // YES! it does ask the user for his password.
            // that.restore();
        };
        var setupFailed = function () {
            log('setup failed');
            options.error(InAppPurchase.ERR_SETUP, 'Setup failed');
        };

        exec('setup', [], setupOk, setupFailed);
    };

    /**
     * Makes an in-app purchase. 
     * 
     * @param {String} productId The product identifier. e.g. "com.example.MyApp.myproduct"
     * @param {int} quantity 
     */
    InAppPurchase.prototype.purchase = function (productId, quantity) {
        quantity = (quantity|0) || 1;
        var options = this.options;
        var purchaseOk = function () {
            log('Purchased ' + productId);
            if (typeof options.purchase === 'function')
                options.purchase(productId, quantity);
        };
        var purchaseFailed = function () {
            var msg = 'Purchasing ' + productId + ' failed';
            log(msg);
            if (typeof options.error === 'function')
                options.error(InAppPurchase.ERR_PURCHASE, msg, productId, quantity);
        };
        return exec('purchase', [productId, quantity], purchaseOk, purchaseFailed);
    };

    /**
     * Asks the payment queue to restore previously completed purchases.
     * The restored transactions are passed to the onRestored callback, so make sure you define a handler for that first.
     * 
     */
    InAppPurchase.prototype.restore = function() {
        return exec('restoreCompletedTransactions', []);
    };

    /**
     * Retrieves localized product data, including price (as localized
     * string), name, description of multiple products.
     *
     * @param {Array} productIds
     *   An array of product identifier strings.
     *
     * @param {Function} callback
     *   Called once with the result of the products request. Signature:
     *
     *     function(validProducts, invalidProductIds)
     *
     *   where validProducts receives an array of objects of the form:
     *
     *     {
     *       id: "<productId>",
     *       title: "<localised title>",
     *       description: "<localised escription>",
     *       price: "<localised price>"
     *     }
     *
     *  and invalidProductIds receives an array of product identifier
     *  strings which were rejected by the app store.
     */
    InAppPurchase.prototype.load = function (productIds, callback) {
        var options = this.options;
        if (typeof productIds === "string") {
            productIds = [productIds];
        }
        if (!productIds.length) {
            // Empty array, nothing to do.
            callback([], []);
        }
        else {
            if (typeof productIds[0] !== 'string') {
                var msg = 'invalid productIds given to store.load: ' + JSON.stringify(productIds);
                log(msg);
                options.error(InAppPurchase.ERR_LOAD, msg);
                return;
            }
            log('load ' + JSON.stringify(productIds));

            var loadOk = function (array) {
                log("loadOk()");
                var valid = array[0];
                var invalid = array[1];
                log('load ok: { valid:' + JSON.stringify(valid) + ' invalid:' + JSON.stringify(invalid) + ' }');
                callback(valid, invalid);
            };
            var loadFailed = function (errMessage) {
                log('load failed: ' + errMessage);
                options.error(InAppPurchase.ERR_LOAD, 'Failed to load product data: ' + errMessage);
            };

            exec('load', [productIds], loadOk, loadFailed);
        }
    };

    /* This is called from native.*/
    InAppPurchase.prototype.updatedTransactionCallback = function (state, errorCode, errorText, transactionIdentifier, productId, transactionReceipt) {
        // alert(state);
        switch(state) {
            case "PaymentTransactionStatePurchased":
                this.options.purchase(transactionIdentifier, productId, transactionReceipt);
                return; 
            case "PaymentTransactionStateFailed":
                this.options.error(errorCode, errorText);
                return;
            case "PaymentTransactionStateRestored":
                this.options.restore(transactionIdentifier, productId, transactionReceipt);
                return;
        }
    };

    InAppPurchase.prototype.restoreCompletedTransactionsFinished = function () {
        this.options.restoreCompleted();
    };

    InAppPurchase.prototype.restoreCompletedTransactionsFailed = function (errorCode) {
        this.options.restoreFailed(errorCode);
    };

    /*
     * This queue stuff is here because we may be sent events before listeners have been registered. This is because if we have 
     * incomplete transactions when we quit, the app will try to run these when we resume. If we don't register to receive these
     * right away then they may be missed. As soon as a callback has been registered then it will be sent any events waiting
     * in the queue.
     */
    InAppPurchase.prototype.runQueue = function () {
        if(!this.eventQueue.length || (!this.onPurchased && !this.onFailed && !this.onRestored)) {
            return;
        }
        var args;
        /* We can't work directly on the queue, because we're pushing new elements onto it */
        var queue = this.eventQueue.slice();
        this.eventQueue = [];
        args = queue.shift();
        while (args) {
            this.updatedTransactionCallback.apply(this, args);
            args = queue.shift();
        }
        if (!this.eventQueue.length) {  
            this.unWatchQueue();
        }
    };

    InAppPurchase.prototype.watchQueue = function () {
        if (this.timer) {
            return;
        }
        this.timer = window.setInterval(function () {
            window.storekit.runQueue();
        }, 10000);
    };

    InAppPurchase.prototype.unWatchQueue = function () {
        if (this.timer) {
            window.clearInterval(this.timer);
            this.timer = null;
        }
    };

    InAppPurchase.eventQueue = [];
    InAppPurchase.timer = null;

    module.exports = new InAppPurchase();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tracked the issue down to two things: first that the console output is not appearing right away because the Objective-C success callback function “didReceiveResponse” comes back on a different thread – pressing the power button to pause the app flushes the buffered log content to the console.

Secondly, a JS error in my success handler function (reference to an undefined variable) was failing silently so this was not obvious.

Comment: Hi Dpa99c, this is great news as for tracking down the cause of the problem. I just pressed the power button and indeed the correct logs appear instantly. Now my question is: how to fix this? I can't really go and tell my users to press their power button to activate an in-app purchase...

Comment: Only the log output is buffered (pressing the power button flushes the log). The callbacks that are executed by the plugin when the StoreKit API receives a response from the remote Apple servers are not affected by this. So since your users don't need to see the logs, so it won't affect them :-)

Comment: Hi Dpa99c, thanks for your comment. So it looks like when an error occurs, the thread gets stuck until the device power button is used, and if no error occurs, everything rolls along nicely?